# Defining a method to update ruby object property

Tags: ruby

Hey I am having trouble with the following question to be solved using ruby.

***Question***

> **Write a function that provides change directory (cd) function for an abstract file system.**
>
> > **Notes:**
> >
> > Root path is '/'.
> >
> > Path separator is '/'.
> >
> > Parent directory is addressable as '..'.
> >
> > Directory names consist only of English alphabet letters (A-Z and a-z).
> >
> > **For example:**
> >
> > path = Path.new('/a/b/c/d')
> >
> > puts path.cd('../x').current_path
> >
> > should display '/a/b/c/x'.
> >
> > **Note:** Do not use built-in path-related functions.

***My Answer***

```
class Path

  def initialize(path)
    @current_path = path
  end  

  def current_path
    @current_path
  end

  def cd(new_path)

    if new_path.include? ".."
      z = new_path.split("/")
      b = @current_path
      a = b.split('/')
      a.shift
      a.pop
      @current_path = a.push(z[z.length-1]).join("/")
    else
    end
  end
end

path = Path.new('/a/b/c/d')
path = path.cd('../x')
```

However this returns a string instead of an object from the 'path' variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a chain method. There are 2 ways to address it.

The immutable one - just create new instance of the class instead of modifying, e.g. `return Path.new(calculated_path)`

The mutable one - modify `@current_path` and return `self` in the end of the method `#cd`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

After you've changed `@current_path` in the object, just return the object ('self')

```
@current_path = a.push(z[z.length-1]).join("/")
return self
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, much appreciated!